# Action not getting called

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am trying to call an action function inside a loop in Ember. I am doing everything by the book I am not sure why the function is never fired.

Here is the bootstrap dropdown that I am using

```
<ul id="dropdown-id" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="width:100%;">
  {{#if isLoadingSearch}}
    <li role="presentation" style="padding:10px;">
      <p class="lead">
        Loading... please wait
      </p>
    </li>
  {{else}}
    {{#each serachUsers}}
      <li role="presentation">
        <a class="btn-link" {{action 'chooseEmail' this}}>
          <p class="lead">
          <img class="img-circle" {{bind-attr src=avatar}} alt="" height="50">
          {{fullname}}
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</ul>
```

Usually the chooseEmail function should get called. It does in all the loops I used with standard tables, but somehow with this dropdown its not firing up

The function is inside actions and inside the correct Controller I am not sure why does this not work.

Here is my code for the controller

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // initial value
  setupController: function(controller, context){
    controller.reset();
  }
});

App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  reset: function(){
    this.setProperties({
      serachUsers:"",
      isLoadingSearch:false,
    });
  },

  actions :{

    queryDB: function(){
      $("#dropdown-id").dropdown('toggle');
      var self = this;
      if (self.get('sellerEmail')) {
        var data = {'oauth_consumer_key':sessionStorage.access_token,'device_id':sessionStorage.device_id,'device_name':'web','query':self.get('sellerEmail')};
        self.set('isLoadingSearch',true);
        $.ajaxSetup({
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
        });

        $.post('/api/v1/user/search/',JSON.stringify(data)).then(function(response){
          if (response.success) {
            self.set('serachUsers',response.users);
            self.set('isLoadingSearch',false);
          };
        });
      };
    },

    chooseEmail: function(user){
      alert('check');
      var self = this;
      self.set('sellerEmail',user.user_id);
      $(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
    },
  },

});
```

## Something funky

So when I got rid of the dropdown  it works just fine,

```
{{#each serachUsers}}
<li role="presentation">
  <a class="btn-link" {{action "chooseEmail" this}}>
    <p class="lead">
    <img class="img-circle" {{bind-attr src=avatar}} alt="" height="50">
    {{fullname}}
    </p>
  </a>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `{{#each serachUsers}}` is "search" supposed to be spelled "serach"?

Comment: @JonnyHenly yes it is a spelling mistake but I had used the same spelling inside my controller. So the list was generated just fine

Comment: @torazaburo no. Even the alert message is not visible

Comment: I'm wondering if the click is getting eaten by the `a` tag, can you try replacing it with `div` or something?

Comment: are you using https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember

Comment: Is serachUsers using an itemController?  or is it just iterating a collection, because your context may not be what you think it is, which is likely what you're problem is, it's attempting to send an action to some item which isn't actionable (the context `this` is probably just an individual item)

Comment: @torazaburo I tried that as well, same issue.

Comment: @rjdmello no just standard bootstrap

Comment: @Kingpin2k please look at the updated code

Comment: Time for some good old-fashioned debugging. Replace the entire content of the `#each` with `<span {{action 'chooseEmail' this}}>Click</span>` and see if that works, and take it from there.

Comment: @torazaburo the same happens. Which is nothing and no log

Comment: Keep debugging. Examine the HTML to see if anything looks amiss. Place a DOM event breakpoint on click and track how it is handled.

Comment: @torazaburo please check the code, something funny is going on